# SOAP with Attachments

Tags: .net, soap

I need to send a SOAP (with attachments) message via a HTTP Post to a third party. The contents of the SOAP Header need to be customised and additional data sent as an attachment. Both the SOAP Header (the child elements within it to be specific) and the attachment need to be signed and included in the SOAP Header. There is no WSDL available so no proxy code can be generated.

The only way i can think of doing this at the moment is to effectively build the message from scratch manually i.e. construct the contents of the SOAP header as a series classes (with the help of XSD.exe), add the signature, serialise it to XML, insert it into a manually constructed MIME message and then finally do something similar with the attachment. While this will give me full control over the contents of the message it feels like a really long winded way of doing something that .NET probably gives me for free.

So i guess my question is, is there a better way of doing this? Can anyone give me some pointers on where to begin? I've been looking into WCF but i don't believe that it supports attachments or custom SOAP headers - is this correct?

Comment: WCF does allow you to do custom headers, but SOAP with Attachments us quite obsolete. Are you sure that's what you need? Not MTOM?

Comment: Unfortunately, the messaging standard that i need to implement is quite explicit in its requirement of SwA. I'm aware that it's obsolete but there's not really anything i can do about that I'm afraid.